# Ant - How to set ${ant.project.name} to project folder name?

Tags: ant

How to set ${ant.project.name} value? I want to set it as:
${ant.project.name}=${basedir}

I don't want to set the project name from build.xml. My idea is - it should take the name of the folder automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

The ANT property **ant.project.name** is designed to return the string that appears at the top of your build file. It has special meaning and shouldn't really be changed.

The following example demonstrates how you could use an alternative property (This should work on windows as well):

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <basename property="my.project.name" file="${basedir}"/>

    <target name="run">
        <echo message="ant.project.name=${ant.project.name}"/>
        <echo message="my.project.name=${my.project.name}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Has the following output

```
run:
     [echo] ant.project.name=demo
     [echo] my.project.name=myprojectdirname
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm just trying to dynamically/automatically assign the project folder name to project name attribute. For e.g. if I create a project folder named 'test', it should be dynamically assigned to project name attribute in build.xml. If I change the project folder's name, it should reflect in build.xml without my intervention. There is a way through setting -Dant.project.name=test. But, here too I'm trying to get the current folder's name automatically. In Windows it's very tricky. for %* in (.) do @echo %~n* gives us the current folder name. Can you tell me how? Thnx!

Comment: @Faisal answer updated. I don't recommend overriding a standard property. Instead use a custom one.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you so intent on setting this specific property when you can set any other property your heart desires? It really doesn't make any sense either. The name of the project is completely independent of the name of the directory where you checked it out to.

However, if you insist, you can set `${ant.project.name}` by not setting it in the `<project>` entity:

```
<project basedir="." default="package"> <!-- Notice no name! -->
    <basename property="ant.project.name"
        file="${basedir}"/>

    <target name="package">
        <echo>The name of this project is ${ant.project.name}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ant.project.name` property is set by Ant at runtime, and can't be changed.  There are a handful of built-in parameters like that, [documented on the Ant website.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html)  If you have a need to properties that you can change, you might be interested in [ant contrib's var.](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)

Comment: When ant -Dant.project.name=test is possible, IMHO, this too should be possible. By the way, I'm trying to assign the current folder name through -D. From DOS, for %* in (.) do @echo %~n* prints the current folder name. I'm trying to assign this to the property -Dant.project.name.