# How can I input project name in command line with ant?

Tags: java, ant

Instead of hard code the project name:

```
<project name="myProject" basedir="src" default="build">
```

I want to input the project name in command line like:

```
ant "myProject"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572174/ant-how-to-set-ant-project-name-to-project-folder-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible if:

- your build file is called `build.xml`,
- in this build file, you have a target called `myProject`.

You could then call another file etc.

Comment: Yes I have build file called `build.xml` and I have target called `myProject`. Can you show an example?

Comment: No, your _project_ is called `myProject`. This is not the same as a target!