# How to rename module in NetBeans Modular project?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I use NetBeans 11.0 and Java 11 for my Modular project. How  I could rename already created module without deleting any file inside of him?
There isn't refactoring for modular projects and modules. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Build tool is Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Maven. In your `pom.xml` you can set the name of the project in the name-tag:

```
<project ...>
    <name>My project name</name>
    ...
</project>
```

For Ant projects have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697072/875083).

Comment: My current project is created with Ant.

Comment: @John see the linked answer for Ant

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I was hopping that there is a way to rename module on one place, that would affect all its references. For those that want to know, another way is to rename folder of module and module info file, but be careful with references in other applications.